# Error while generating Mnemonic

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, accounts

I want to generate Mnemonic for creating an account, I was using the following code
and I got the error as

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'entropyToMnemonic' of undefined

I am sure I am missing something

```
> var ethers = require('ethers')
undefined
> const mnemonic = 
ethers.HDNode.entropyToMnemonic(ethers.utils.randomBytes(16))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the `utils` in there:

```
ethers.utils.HDNode.entropyToMnemonic()
```

(i.e. It's in the [`utils/hdnode.js`](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/09b698b0a9da4b77554f5808911ddf6066fbc0d9/utils/hdnode.js#L199) file.)